# Why can't the driver find a method in a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I made a Magic Square program and it is about done, however, One of the methods in my class can't be called from the main method. I have two methods in the class and only one out of the two is not found.  `noRep` is a method that makes sure the inputted numbers aren't repeated. When I try to use it from the main method, the compiler says

> cannot find symbol method noRep (int[][])

Here is the class:

```
public class MagicClass
{
    public static boolean noRep(int[][] square)
    {
        int[] one = new int[10];


        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            one[i] = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {

                if (square[i][j] < 1 || square[i][j] > 9)
                    return false;

                one[square[i][j]]++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            if (one[i] != 1)
                return false;

        return true;
}


public static boolean checkSums(int[][] square)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            sum += square[i][j];


        if (sum != 15)
            return false;
    }


    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            sum += square[i][j];


        if (sum != 15)
            return false;
    }


    if (square[0][0] + square[1][1] + square[2][2] != 15)
        return false;

    if (square[0][2] + square[1][1] + square[2][0] != 15)
        return false;

    return true;
}
}
```

Here is the main method:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MagicSquares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] square = new int[3][3];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    MagicClass MagicSqr = new MagicClass();
    //checkFrequency Frequent = new checkFrequency(square); TESTING
    //void Fre = MagicClass.checkFrequency (square); TESTING
    System.out.println("Please enter your magic square.");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            square[i][j] = input.nextInt();

    if (checkSums(square && noRep(square)))
        System.out.println("You have a magic square");
    else
        System.out.println("Not a magic square");
}
}
```

Comment: `MagicSquare.noRep`

Comment: how would I declare that? I tried to store an initialization into a variable but did not know what variable to use. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @user1211, no need for object, method is static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling noRep in a different class.
Since it is a static method (class level method), instance is not needed. Call it using the following:

```
if (MagicClass.checkSums(square) && MagicClass.noRep(square))
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not really sure how to use `MagicClass.noRep(square)`. Would I replace it with `noRep(square)` ? Or would I place it above somewhere? I am bad at dealing with made up methods in another class.

Comment: That's not going to work either. It should be if (MagicClass.checkSums(square) && MagicClass.noRep(square))